# Placing the empty file in multiple location using shutil

Tags: python, shutil

I have a file called 'Ready.txt' in the source and I want to have a copy of this file in multiple folders.

This is the code I wrote. But these copies only to the sample2 folder but not to other folders. I am missing something please let me know what is wrong.

```
import shutil
import os


source = r'D:/Users/Desktop'
dest = r'D:/Users/Documents'
dest1 = dest + '/sample2'
dest2 = dest + '/sample3'
dest3 = dest + '/sample4'
files = os.listdir(source)





for f in files:
    f_path = os.path.join(source , f)
    if (f.startswith('Ready.txt')):
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest1)
    elif (f.startswith('Ready.txt')):
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest2)
    elif (f.startswith('Ready.txt')):
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest3)

print('done')
```

Expected output:

```
sample2 folder        
Ready.txt 

sample3 folder        
Ready.txt 

sample4 folder        
Ready.txt
```

Comment: Remove the two `elif` lines.

Comment: If i remove it then how does it get pasted to other folders?

Comment: Because you will be left with three `shutil.copy(...)` lines, so the file will be copied three times to three different locations.

Comment: this kinda works. With my below answer as per your idea. Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you looping over all the files in the source folder if you only want to copy one file? You already know the full path of "Ready.txt", so just copy it three times to the required locations.

Comment: Could you please post your solution? Coz I  know I wrote a big query for a simple tasks.

Comment: I can't post a solution, because your current code doesn't make much sense. Again: why are you looping over all the files in the source folder if you only want to copy one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code is always falling into first IF

you have the same condition for every statement

PS
you can drop unnecessary round brackets in Python

```
import shutil
import os


source = r'D:/Users/Desktop'
dest = r'D:/Users/Documents'
dest1 = dest + '/sample2'
dest2 = dest + '/sample3'
dest3 = dest + '/sample4'
files = os.listdir(source)





for f in files:
    f_path = os.path.join(source , f)
    if f.startswith('Ready.txt'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest1)
    elif f.startswith('Ready2.txt'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest2)
    elif f.startswith('Ready3.txt'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest3)

print('done')
```

Edit1:
according to comment you need file to be in multiple locs, then just do:

```
import shutil
import os


source = r'D:/Users/Desktop'
dest = r'D:/Users/Documents'
dest1 = dest + '/sample2'
dest2 = dest + '/sample3'
dest3 = dest + '/sample4'
files = os.listdir(source)





for f in files:
    f_path = os.path.join(source , f)
    if f.startswith('Ready.txt'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest1)
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest2)
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest3)

print('done')
```

Comment: The idea here is to place the same copy of Ready.txt file in multiple locations and I do not want to create Readt2, Ready3 etc... I have only one file called Ready.txt

Comment: @KSp see modification